# Imported module running at execution of specified script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several imports at the head of a `main.py` file.

```
from python_elements import statistics
from python_elements import trade
from python_elements import advisory
```

When I execute `main.py`, the line of code `initial_action = input("action: ")` is supposed to output a prompt as follows:

```
action:
```

However, the prompts that are built into `advisory.py`, one of the imported scripts, are given instead, causing the output when I run `main.py` to look like this:

```
symbol:
```

as the corresponding code from the top of `advisory.py` looks like this:

```
symbol = input("symbol: ")
```

I am unsure as to why an import statement would cause these lines to run first, so what am I missing?

Comment: maybe you are using an `__init__.py` file inside a `python_elements` directory, so you are running advisory.py wich contain symbol variable. Try `from advisory import *` or check how to import modules in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any code that is part of the top-level/global scope will be executed on import. This is how classes, functions etc. are created - by executing the code that defines them.

You should write modules that you expect will be imported with a guard condition that prevents unwanted execution on import. Here is an example, assume the module file is named `example.py`:

```
class C:
    pass

def func():
    pass

print(__name__)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    symbol = input("symbol: ")
```

If you were to run the module as a script with `python example.py`, Python will set the value of the special `__name__` variable to the string `"__main__"`, and the print statement would output `__main__`. In this case the code within the body of the `if` statement would be executed because the condition `__name__ == '__main__'` will be True. `

However, if the module is imported with `import example`, `__name__` will be set to the name of the module (`example` in our case) and the print statement would output `example`. The code that defines the classes and functions will still be executed, but the code in body of the `if` statement is prevented from running by the condition `__name__ == '__main__'` which is False.